# How can I refer to 2 differents dataset into a gsheet query formula?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a formula to match 2 different data set in google sheets.
I did the following but I keep getting "parse error"

```
iferror(if(len($D10)> 0,
      query({'Sheet1'!$A$2:$T;'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}
            "select {'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}.B where {'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}.A contains 'condition2'
                and {'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}.D contains'"&$D$4&"
                and {'Sheet1'!$A$2:$T}.N >= date '"&text(($A$4), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
                and {'Sheet1'!$A$2:$T}.N <= date '"&text(($B$4), "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'",0),""),"")
```

With D10 is the cell that I'll look up the match for.

Let me know if you have any tips and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The syntax for [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) is `QUERY(data, query, [headers])`

In your case, you forgot the `,` between the `data` and the `query`.

It should be `...query({'Sheet1'!$A$2:$T;'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}, "select {'Sheet2'!$A$2:$BK}.B where...`